# Make http WebRequest work in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I want to get a respond from an http website,I have used this code

```
// Create a new request to the mentioned URL.    
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/NosazMohaseb/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=NosazMohaseb:GParcelLAyer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&bbox=5727579.437775434,3838435.3419322656,5727581.1322169611,3838437.0363737918");

//   var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
myWebRequest.Method ="GET";
myWebRequest.Timeout = TimeOut;

if (myWebRequest is HttpWebRequest)
{
   ( myWebRequest as HttpWebRequest).Accept = "application/json";
    (myWebRequest as HttpWebRequest).ContentType = "application/json";
    //(myWebRequest as HttpWebRequest).Accept = 
    (myWebRequest as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
    (myWebRequest as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "SharpMap-WMSLayer";
}

if (Credentials != null)
{
    myWebRequest.Credentials = Credentials;
    myWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
}
else
    myWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

if (Proxy != null)
    myWebRequest.Proxy = Proxy;

try
{
    using (var myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse())
    {           
        using (var dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var cLength = (int)myWebResponse.ContentLength;
        }
        myWebResponse.Close();
    }
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
    if (!this.ContinueOnError)
        throw (new RenderException(
            "There was a problem connecting to the WMS server when rendering layer '" + LayerName + "'",
            webEx));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (!ContinueOnError)
        throw (new RenderException("There was a problem rendering layer '" + LayerName + "'", ex));
}
```

But when I try to get `cLength` it is `-1`,So it does not work,But When I try to access this website

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/NosazMohaseb/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=NosazMohaseb:GParcelLAyer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&bbox=5727579.437775434,3838435.3419322656,5727581.1322169611,3838437.0363737918
```

I get following answer

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":2,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"GParcelLAyer.14970","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5727597.96542913,3838442.73401128],[5727595.60003176,3838429.21114233],[5727576.62444883,3838431.10604568],[5727571.16785106,3838432.76483769],[5727569.78420277,3838437.30665986],[5727570.19434939,3838439.63808217],[5727597.96542913,3838442.73401128]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"FK_BlockNo":"12055","FK_LandNo":"8","NoApart":"100000","Name":"                    ","Family":"??","Father":"                    ","MeliNo":"          ","MalekType":"1   ","PostCode":"0         ","Id_Parvande":null,"BuildNo":null,"BuildTypeCode":null,"BuildUserTypeCode":null,"BuildViewTypeCode":null,"BuildGhedmatCode":null,"Farsoode":"0"}}],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::900913"}}}
```

So it seems I am missing somthing while getting respond using C#..Can you please help me find my mistake?
thanks

Comment: here's a nice and simple example on how to do it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Nudity thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're actually just getting response stream and  later you're not reading anything from this stream - that's why you're not getting any data.

You have to create stream reader and use it to read data from response stream (consider to use buffered `Read` instead of `ReadToEnd` if your data size is large):

```
using (var dataStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Concerning `ContentLength` equals to -1 in your case - well, it can be something at your server-side, check if your server actually returns this header. In fact, this header is not mandatory and you should not rely on it.